# Solid state relay (contactor) and polarity/direction of current for its output

Tags: solid-state-relay, contactor

I'm looking at a [Crydom HDC100D160](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/657/hdc_series_panel_mount_ssr_datasheet-2933872.pdf).  This picture is really all the detail the datasheet provides as far as usage.

[image: Diagram from Datasheet]

On the output side, does the polarity for my DC equipment or the direction of charge really matter?  My application is to connect a solar system to a battery. At different times, I need to either charge the battery when the sun is out or to have the battery provide power for the system when the sun is not out.

Answer (score 0):

The data sheet clearly indicates that the polarity is important.

+/L1  -/L2

Answer (score 0):

> *On the output side does it really matter on the polarity for my DC
> equipment or of the direction of charge?*

On this model yes, it does. Look at the MOSFET symbol in your diagram; it incorporates a diode and current will always flow in that direction irrespective of whether the relay is activated or not: -

[image]

The clue is in the part number: HDC100 implies a DC output where polarity is important. If you look at a [HAC model](https://www.sensata.com/sites/default/files/a/hac-series-ac-panel-mount-ssr-datasheet.pdf) from Crydom, it can have an AC load current: -

[image]
[image]

Comment: However, as the HAC model uses thyristors for its output, it can *only* have an AC load. It can't control a DC load that may need reverse charging current.

Comment: Precisely, it is only suitable if the AC commutates the thyristors @Hearth. I'm not recommending this part; I'm just pointing out that the DC part in the device product name means it cannot be used to switch an AC voltage on and off effectively.